# How do you add an optional string literal in a route url?

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to add an optional parameter at the end of a url for specifiying the format. Ideally it would work like this:

Both `localhost/details/42` and `localhost/details/42.xml` would point to the same action.

Currently I have defined the route like this

```
routes.MapRoute("with_Format", "Details/{id}.{format}", 
    new { controller = "Person", action = "Details" });
routes.MapRoute("without_format", "Details/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Person", action = "Details" });
```

I would like to do this with one route definition. I know you can add an optional url segments like  `"Details/{id}{format}, new { format = UrlParameter.Optional}`; however, you aren't allowed to have two path segments that are not separated by a literal character. Is there a way to make the `.{format}` optional or do I need to use two routes to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the separator and set format as optional or set it a default if you need a value in all cases. It's similar to default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "OptionalFormat",
    Details/{id}.{format},
    new { controller = "Person", action = "Details", format = UrlParameter.Optional /* or "xml" */ }
);
```

Since there's nothing proceeding `format` segment, it can therefore be optional. If there was something non-optional and without a default afterwards, `format` would always have to be specified. But in your case `format` is the last segment.

Define it as an optional parameter (which means you will get nothing into your action when format won't be specified) or give it a default value (which means you'll always get something even though nothing'd be specified).